# Using stripos function in PHP but having conflict with variable

Tags: php, stripos

I am trying to solve an issue with a function stripos in PHP. We are doing promo codes and for instance, one promo code is "friends" and another is "friends40" and when someone types that in, it is saying that both of these are true so it will give them a double discount.

We need these to be distinct but not case sensitive. Is there a technique or another function we can use?

```
if (stripos($promo,'friends') !== false) {   
$price = $price/2;
$adddiscount = .50;
}
if (stripos($promo,'FRIENDS40') !== false) {   
$price = $price - $price * .4;
$adddiscount = .4;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both will validate as `stripos` is **case-insensitive** and `friends` can be found in `FRIENDS40`. You need to do the `FRIENDS40` check first then the `friends`

```
<?php
if(stripos($promo,'FRIENDS40') !== false) {   
    $price = $price - $price * .4;
    $adddiscount = .4;
}elseif(stripos($promo,'friends') !== false) {   
    $price = $price/2;
    $adddiscount = .50;
}
```

An alternative would be to use [strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) which **IS case-sensitive**:

```
<?php
if(strpos($promo,'FRIENDS40') !== false) {   
    $price = $price - $price * .4;
    $adddiscount = .4;
}
if(strpos($promo,'friends') !== false) {   
    $price = $price/2;
    $adddiscount = .50;
}
```

To be on the safe side I would recommend using the first method.

Comment: By putting the friends40 first, it didnt work. It still is processing both scripts.